# Elasticsearch, aggregation, how to count accurately in the estimated final list

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

elasticSearch (ES) term aggregation result is approximate in term of the finalists and their counts. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

I'd like to have the accurate counts for the for the estimated finalists, despite that the finalist are not accurate. I want to eliminate per bucket document count error.

I am thinking to issue a second query that's filtered by the finalists, and since I know the number of finalists, I can count them accurately if I set size=#finalists.

Using the example from the link above: after I have the top 5 Products: a,z,c,g,b from the first aggregation result, I want to find their accurate counts:

```
{
    ...

    "aggregations" : {
        "products" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 46,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Product A",
                    "doc_count" : 100,
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Product Z",
                    "doc_count" : 52,
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 2
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now the doc_counts are estimated, I can issue a second query filtered by the product ids:

```
{ 
  ...
  "query": { 
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {"product": ["Product A", "Product Z","Product C","Product G","Product B"]} 
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs":{
    "products":{
      "terms":{
        "field": "product",
        "size": 5, 
        "shard_size": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. does this give me the correct counts on a,z,c,g,b?
2. is there a better way to do this? inside one query, maybe nested aggregation?
3. the parsing aggregation results to prepare filters is done with JAVA code, and it is error-prone. Is there an example of this task? or can it be done by ES ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might achieve the goal but keep in mind this will not catch the corner case where a product was not in the top 5 because it was 6th in every shard while the sum of each 6th would put it in the top 5 among the 3 shards

Comment: @isaac.hazan , yes, you are right, I am not trying to avoid that type of errors, I just want the accurate counting of the maybe-wrong final list.

Comment: You could try combining the cardinality aggregation along with your terms aggregation. Keep in mind though that cardinality has an error margin of ~5% (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate)